How to Retrieve Individual Elements from a Comma-Separated List Defined with \newcommand?
This question builds on the answer provided here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732630/278762.
I am trying to work with a comma-separated list in LaTeX. Suppose I define a list using \newcommand as follows:
\newcommand{\mylist}{one,two,three,four,five}
When I use the \setList{\mylist} command, the entire content one,two,three,four,five is treated as a single element, rather than being split into five individual elements one, two, three, four, five.
Why does this happen, and how can I retrieve specific elements (e.g., the first element) from a list defined using \newcommand?
MY CODE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_marco_clist
\NewDocumentCommand\setList{m}
{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_marco_clist {#1}
}
% list counts from 1
\NewDocumentCommand\getItem{m}
{
    \clist_item:Nn \l_marco_clist {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
    
\begin{document}
    
    \newcommand{\mylist}{one,two,three,four,five}

    My list is: \mylist
    
    \setList{\mylist}
    
    The first element of the list is: \getItem{1}
    
\end{document}


OUTPUT:


sorry, but why don't you just say \setList{one,two...}? if you really need to use another command, you need to expand it before the list parsing sees it. e.g. \ExpandArgs {e} \setList {\mylist}, but if you use something in the list which shouldn't be expanded yet, you would need to protect it or control the expansion more carefully e.g. \ExpandArgs {o} \setList {\mylist}.

THAAAANKS :) It works as expected :) Better Don't ask why I did that this way, but it must be this way. This comes from a longer stupid code I wrote :(

It would be better to use an L3 clist variable but if you are committed to using a document level name, it still works:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% list counts from 1
\NewDocumentCommand\getItem{m}
{
    \clist_item:Nn \mylist {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
    
\begin{document}
    
    \newcommand{\mylist}{one,two,three,four,five}

    My list is: \mylist
    
    
    The first element of the list is: \getItem{1}
    
\end{document}


huh. so much for the claims they make in the ads for the crystal ball I got.

I guess you'll have several of these lists in your document class, so it's better to set up a generic interface.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_unitn_bozo_clist

% user interface for populating the list
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddBozos}{m}
 {
  \clist_put_right:Nn \l_unitn_bozo_clist {#1}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \unitn_get_item:Nn
 {% #1 = clist, #2 = item number
  \clist_item:Nn #1 {#2}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \unitn_print_clist:Nn
 {% #1 = clist, #2 = item separator
  \clist_use:Nn #1 {#2}
 }

% a user level version for testing
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetBozo}{m}
 {
  \unitn_get_item:Nn \l_unitn_bozo_clist {#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintBozos}{O{,~}}
 {
  \unitn_print_clist:Nn \l_unitn_bozo_clist {#1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddBozos{one,two}
\AddBozos{three}
\AddBozos{four,five}

\GetBozo{3}

\PrintBozos

\begin{itemize}
\item \PrintBozos[\item]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


